# print each element of a list in diferent line

Tags: python, list, paramiko

I build a code in python to write list in a file whit one element per line.

I have tried whit "\n" at the end, whit ast.literal_eval and whit .join

```py
y=list(map(int, y)) #convert my list in int for increment one element per one
print(y) #test my list
y[0]+=1 #increment one element of my list per one
print(y) #test my new list
y=str(y) # convert my int list in str list

f = sftp.open("/home/pi/SiteCyberdependance/data/data.txt", "w+") 
with sftp.open("/home/pi/SiteCyberdependance/donne/donne.txt", "w") as f: #open the file
            sftp=paramiko.SFTPFile.write
            for elem in y:
               f.write(y) #write my list
```

the result here is many time the item of the list write all in the same line whit a space between, but I need my list write in diferent line, like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

[my result most of my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9bGe.jpg)

Comment: If you replace `f.write(y)` with `f.write(y + '\n')`, does it fix your problem?

Comment: no, I have try it

Comment: How are you looking at the result? What OS are you using?

Comment: I use filezila and i'm in window 10

Comment: Please open the file with notepad++ instead notepad. Also, you can debug with notepad++ with `show all character feature`. Or share your result file.

Comment: the file where I write my list is just a text file, they have no code

Comment: so I guess sftp doesn't have the same behavior as standard python text files (which substitute `/n` for os.linesep) have you tried using `f.write(y + os.linesep)`?